# Understanding operator norms

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
                     0 & 1 & 0\\
                     0 & 0 & 1\\
                     0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

Please help explain the fault in the following reasoning:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, write $k = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$

Then $\|A\| = max_k\|Ak\|=\|e_1k_2 + e_2k_3\|=2$

The given answer is $1$, where is the mistake?

Comment: What is $I_3$? And how did you arrive at $2I_3$ from the previous step?

Comment: Silly error, meant $2$. Take $k_2=(1,0,0), k_3=(0,1,0)$ I also realize this now does not equal 2, but it still does not equal 1 so there is still a mistake I'm making.

Comment: What is the norm of $k$ in that case?

Comment: Incidentally, what norm are you talking about? Euclidean? If so, 2 isn't right even for that value of $k$. (But one thing at a time.)

Comment: Oh you're correct then. I then have the bound $\|e_1k_2 + e_2k_3\| \le ||e_1k_2\|+\|e_2k_3\|$. And yes I realized your second comment, I'm talking about Euclidean. I'm unsure of how the norms of the $k_i$ relate to norm $k$ being 1.

Comment: Why don't you just write out the explicit formulas for the norms of $k$ and $Ak$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: note that
$$
\|k_2e_1 + k_3 e_2\|^2 = 
k_2^2 + k_3^2 \leq
k_1^2 + k_2^2 + k_3^2 =
\|k\|^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, but any direction on how to argue $max_k\|Ak\|\ge1$?

Comment: Sure.  Choose a vector $k$ so that $\|Ak\| = \|k\|$.

Comment: Great and I understand the similar problems now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The operator norm is defined (equivalently) as any of :
$\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$
$\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|\leq1}\|Ax\|$
$\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$

Above, you test against $k = (0,1,1)$ (I'm not sure what you mean by $e_1k_2+e_2k_3)$ - you're multiplying vectors here, which makes little sense in context, and none at all without specifying if you are using the cross or dot product), which has (Euclidian) norm $\sqrt{2}$, so if you wish to use it to test your operator norm, you need to use the third formula above, and $\frac{\|Ak\|_2}{\|k\|_2} = \frac{\|(1,1,0)\|_2}{\|(0,1,1)\|_2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = 1$, so you have a witness that $\|A\| \geq 1$. In order to prove that $\|A\| = 1$, you now need to show that $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}^3$ (or possibly faster, using the first formula, $\|Ax\|_2 \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\|x\|_2 = 1$.

(NB: Throughout (except in the definition of the operator norm, which applies on any normed linear space) I've made the use of the Euclidian norm explicit by denoting it $\|\cdot\|_2$ - this is not actually important).

Comment: $e_1$ and $e_2$ are just the unit vectors with 1 in the first and second entries, respectively. They are the second and third columns of his matrix $A$. That part of his derivation is right.

Comment: The issue is with the line $\|e_1k_2+e_2k_3\|=2$, where he multiplied these vectors by other vectors, then took a norm, which he seems to intend to be the 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note the comment where he defined $k_2=(1,0,0),k_3=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Well no, $k_2$ and $k_3$ are scalars. There's nothing ill-posed about the construct $\|e_1k_2+e_2k_3\|$; claiming it was equal to $2$ was the problem :-)

Comment: Note the comment on the question - he very much took them to be vectors there.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.